# How to run an .exe and capture the output in an Eclipse Plugin. (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capturing stdout when calling Runtime.exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec)

Ok so,

I am developing an Eclipse plugin that generates some PHP code based a visual interface (i.e. the user drags and drops some stuff on a View and then my plugin will update some php files with the code associated)

I am creating the php files with FileUtils (Apache Commons) and I am generating the PHP code using an ASTParser.

My problem is that I need my freshly generated code to be beautified and nicely indented. I have googled around and found this http://www.waterproof.fr/products/phpCodeBeautifier/ . It comes as a .exe file. I have added it to resources but I'm having some trouble calling it and getting the output from it.

How can I do this? Also I have to say that I need it to work on both a Mac and a Windows machine. Can this be done? Is there an easier way to beautify the code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can run it from command line and pass file path to beautify the code you can use following code to run it and capture the result.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("executable.exec");

BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

while ((String line = input.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

see also :
[How to capture the data returned from an EXE excuted from a batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796239/how-to-capture-the-data-returned-from-an-exe-excuted-from-a-batch)

[How can i get the console output generated by a exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251039/how-can-i-get-the-console-output-generated-by-a-exe-file/1251045#1251045)

[Capturing stdout when calling Runtime.exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follows:

1. Resolve the location of the exe in an OS independent manner.
2. Create a `Process` using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec('exe_location');
3. Take the `process.getOutputStream()` and print the unformatted code into it which means the exe would read the text to be formatted on STDIN.
4. Take the `process.getInputStream()` and read out the formatted code from it which means the exe would print the formatted output on to STDOUT.
5. Close the streams and end the process.